# Does Oracle Support Events?

Tags: oracle, events, scheduling, scheduled-tasks, oracle11g

[MySQL supports events](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html) where i can set up something to happen in a specified time period

Eg: Update the salary's every month

Eg: Update something every year

Eg: Change the status of a book to "overdue" in a week

Etc etc etc

How do I do this in Oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to do perform scheduled events.

Official Documentation:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm

Alternate: http://www.comp.dit.ie/btierney/oracle11gdoc/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm

Comment: In 9i or earlier DBMS_JOB does the same thing, only with less flexibility.